# Intercepting Supabase.from in Flutter for testing

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I'm trying to intercept `supabase.from()` so that I can start testing my Flutter app. But since `.execute()` as been depreciated, I don't understand how `supabase.from().select()` works. I tried intercepting the `.then()` since it always throw me an error saying it hasn't been implemented.

the code gives me this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
MissingStubError (MissingStubError: 'then'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
then(Closure: (List<Map<String, dynamic>>) => dynamic, {onError: Closure: (Object, StackTrace) => dynamic})
```

Here's my original code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

import 'supabase_test.mocks.dart';

// Generate a MockClient using the Mockito package.
// Create new instances of this class in each test.
//  dart run build_runner build
@GenerateMocks([
  SupabaseClient,
  SupabaseQueryBuilder,
  PostgrestFilterBuilder,
])
void main() {
  group('Supabase mock', () {
    test("description", () async {
      final supabase = MockSupabaseClient();
      final queryBuilder = MockSupabaseQueryBuilder();
      final filterBuilder = MockPostgrestFilterBuilder<PostgrestList>();

      final PostgrestList mockData = [
        {'email_preferences': true}
      ];

      final mockResponse = PostgrestResponse(data: mockData, status: 200);

      when(supabase.from(any)).thenAnswer((_) => queryBuilder);
      when(queryBuilder.select<PostgrestList>(any)).thenAnswer((_) => filterBuilder);
      when(filterBuilder.then(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => mockResponse);

      final data = await supabase.from("profiles").select<PostgrestList("email_preferences");
      final emailPreferences = data[0]['email_preferences'] as bool;
      expect(emailPreferences, true);
    });
  });
}
```

I'm new to Flutter testing and testing in general so maybe I'm missing something important. So if someone could provide me with any help, I would be pleased !

Comment: Here, what you are doing is testing someone else's code (Supabase's code in this case). You shouldn't do that in testing in general, and you should be testing the code that you write. You can put Supabase in a class (call it SupabaseProvider or something) and mock the class containing Supabase.